# WPF, XMAL percentage spacing gets calculated all wrong

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

### In short

My understanding is, by using the * in xaml you should get "fixed" percentages. However, even when adding two grids to an control with the exact same Row- and Columndefinitions the calculations seem to be different.

### tl;dr

**What I wish to do**

I wanted to create a user control with a canvas or button to open a color picker. Whilst designing that control I stumbled across a problem I cannot explain myself.

The left hand side of the control should be nearly a complete mirrored copy of the right hand side with a small difference: the very outer lines should differ in their appearance slightly. Whilst the left line should be short, the right one should drop to the very bottom of the control in order to encapsulate a textblock.

**My approach**

In order to achieve this, I have created a "main" grid to host the three elements (Left hand design grid, center control to open the color picker and right hand grid). Ive added the center control encapsulated by a grid, just to stay consistent with my approaches for the left and right hand side.

Moving on, I have added two grids for the mentioned left and right hand side and gave them the exactly same Row- and Columndefinitions. Thinking that would do the trick, I have added a few lines to add the wished designed to the control.

**The problem**

I've soon noticed, that the two horizontal lines did not match up. The lines had a few pixels in between so I have tried playing around with the layout to find out, what causes that problem.

**The 'solution'**

It seems like everything seems to behave correctly, except for the most right hand line. Whenever its `Grid.RowSpan` is set to 4, meaning it will stretch to the bottom of the control, it messes with the spacing of the percentages. Out of some reason I cannot fathom it seems to change the percentages calculated by the `Grid.RowDefinition`s

Simply setting the `Grid.ColumnSpan="4"` to `Grid.ColumnSpan="3"` for the right most line does fix the spacing, changing the `Grid.ColumnSpan="4"` to `Grid.ColumnSpan="3"` on the most outer left line would also change the spacing correctly.

**A new problem**

This attempt does obviously fix the spacing but does introduce a new problem: the design of the user control with either of the two fixes has changed. Either both lines have to be dropped to the very bottom of the control or both lines have to be short.

And I **really** wish for the two lines to differ slightly. Furthermore, the two vertical lines at the center do not seem to affect the spacing negatively at all, even though they span the discussed rows as well.

**Another solution?**

I've simply went ahead and changed all lines to be canvases with a black background color. That does fix the issue and everything is presented correctly. But yet I am sitting here, not understanding why that problem has occurred in the first place. **I wish to understand what may have caused the changed the calculation of percentages** to improve my knowledge on designing UIs with XAML.

However, the controls preview seems to work now, but when "consumed" by another control (meaning I've added that control to another control) it seems like the entire spacing is all wrong again, just as it was when I've used lines.

**A new culprit**

Upon playing around I've noticed when removing the textbox the spacing would be correct again, even when consumed by another control. Still, my problem here is to understand how that could be an issue even though the percentages should all be the same, leaving no room for the horizontal lines to differ.

Naturally I wondered whether the negative margin could cause the error (that is there in order for the TextBlock to move closer to the line). But with or without margin, the error still consists.

**A more general question**

I know, general question on best approaches and practices are not very welcomed here, but please let me ask at least about resources on how to design well written Controls with XAML. All I've read the past weeks helped me a great lot, and yet I seem to stumble across many problems on a regularly basis.

I cannot tell you where I've read this on the Microsoft docs site, but it clearly stated that one should try to avoid the use of canvases. Maybe I've misunderstood, however, it does seem to me like using a canvas here seems to be a cheap trick to avoid a simple problem I've had with the lines.

Furthermore, if anyone has any idea on how to change the controls layout in order to achieve the desired output please let me know. Thank you in advance for even taking the time to read through this.

### Resources

User-control with lines

**Problem:** Displaying the horizontal lines slightly off

```
<UserControl ...
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="50"  d:DesignWidth="400"
             MinHeight="50">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="54"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- left hand side grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Line Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                  X1="0" X2="0"
                  Y1="0" Y2="1"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Line Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                  X1="0" X2="1"
                  Y1="0" Y2="0"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Line Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                  X1="0" X2="0"
                  Y1="0" Y2="1"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- middle grid -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="0">
            <Canvas Margin="2, 0"
                    Background="Red"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- right hand side grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Line Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                  X1="0" X2="0"
                  Y1="0" Y2="1"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Line Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                  X1="0" X2="1"
                  Y1="0" Y2="0"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Line Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4"
                  X1="0" X2="0"
                  Y1="0" Y2="1"
                  Stroke="Black"
                  StrokeThickness="1"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Text="Prefered Color"
                       FontSize="20"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                       Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Margin="4, -3, 4, 0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[User-control as displayed in designer with horizontal lines being off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/my2g7.png)

User-control with Canvases

**Problem:** Seems to work in the preview but will be miscalculated when added to another control

```
<UserControl ...
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="50"  d:DesignWidth="400"
             MinHeight="50">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="54"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- left hand side grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="0"
              Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                  Background="Black"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                  Background="Black"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                  Background="Black"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- middle grid -->
        <Grid Grid.Column="1"
              Grid.Row="0">
            <Canvas Margin="2, 0"
                    Background="Red"/>
        </Grid>

        <!-- right hand side grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Column="2"
              Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                  Background="Black"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Canvas Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                  Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                  Background="Black"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
            <Canvas Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                  Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="4"
                  Background="Black"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                       Text="Prefered Color"
                       FontSize="20"
                       FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                       Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"
                       Foreground="Black"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                       Margin="4, 0, 4, 0"/>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

[User-control with canvases instead of lines being displayed correctly in designer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ko0KQ.png)

[User-control displayed wrong after being added to another control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRuRX.png)

Comment: To let you know, I have also tried to have a single grid. Yet the calculations there where wrong as well. The grid had three row definitions with sizes *, 1, *. For some strange reason the row with the height set to 1px was displayed way bigger than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will post this as an answer, since it fulfills the neccessary design needs, and mark it as an correct answer for the time beeing. **However**, this answer does not statisfy my question completly since it does not explain why the previous approach didnt work.

Therefore feel free to add answers and I will choose the answer wich explains the issue as the correct one.

```
<UserControl ...
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="50"  d:DesignWidth="400"
             MinHeight="50">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="1"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="40"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="1"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Button Grid.Column="3"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                Margin="4,0"
                Background="Red"
                BorderThickness="0"
                Command="{Binding ColorClick}">
        </Button>

        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5"
                   Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                   Text="Prefered Color"
                   FontSize="20"
                   FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                   Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"
                   Foreground="Black"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                   Margin="4, 0, 4, 0"/>

        <Canvas Grid.Column="0"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="3"
                Background="Black"/>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="1"
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                Background="Black"/>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="2"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                Background="Black"/>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="4"
                Grid.Row="0" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                Background="Black"/>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="5"
                Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="1"
                Background="Black"/>
        <Canvas Grid.Column="6"
                Grid.Row="1" Grid.RowSpan="5"
                Background="Black"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```